# 'Error': 'JSON parse error - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)' How do I fix this

Tags: python-3.x, request

I am writing a script to make requests from different web services. I am having problem when posting data from the json data below. When I run the 
`patient_create_bill()`function I get the logs  below from response.

```
RESPONSE IS!!!!!
{'Error': 'JSON parse error - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)'}
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): 0.0.0.0:9000
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://0.0.0.0:9000 "POST /api/bill/patient/bills/ HTTP/1.1" 400 72
Creating Patient Bill .....................................
```

I have attempted to make a `POST` on post man I get `201` response meaning the payload is fine there is nothing wrong with it. 
[image]

**This is my `POST` payload.**
I have a separate file called `mocks.py` contains 
has `PATIENT_BILL_CREATE_PAYLOAD`

```
PATIENT_BILL_CREATE_PAYLOAD = {
    "bill_items": [{
        "item": "Syringes",
        "qty": 2,
        "description": "Medicorp syringes"
    }],
    "bill_services": [{
        "service": "Diagnosis",
        "service_type": "1",
        "duration": 5,
        "description": "diagnosis"
    }],
    "client": "Sandra Hernandez"
}
```

**This is the function**
i've imported the `PATIENT_BILL_CREATE_PAYLOAD` and using it in this function.

```
def patient_create_bill(headers):
    """This function uses login creds provided and returns token plus logged in user data."""
    url = "http://0.0.0.0:9000/api/bill/patient/bills/"
    data = PATIENT_BILL_CREATE_PAYLOAD
    res = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
    res_data = res.json()
    print("Creating Patient Bill .....................................\n")
    return res_data
```

Comment: What is the value of `res.text`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your own answer is right (encode your data to json), and here is the code fixed. This worked for me:

instead of

```
res = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
```

the correct way to write it is...

```
import json

...

res = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)

# or

res = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)
```

More info about this type of requests in [requests library docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests).

Answer (score 1):

My error was because of using data instead of json in request and also specified the header `Content-Type` as `application/json :-).

Answer (score 0):

This log tells that you not received body in HTTP reponse (HTTP CODE 400):
`DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://0.0.0.0:9000 "POST /api/bill/patient/bills/ HTTP/1.1" 400 72`

Python trying to parse emtry string.
You can run this:

```
import json
json.loads('')
```

And this code will raise:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I think, you should check your URL endpoint to call.

Comment: The url is fine I checked it